# Overlay border of parent element with no color

Tags: css

Is there a way to overlay a parent border with some variable background color?
I am trying to get a `span` within a `p` element with a fixed border to not show the `p's` border. I could overlay it with a white border but then it would be visible in dark mode.

The p needs the border-bottom since it is supposed to run until the end of frame (like ruled paper).

This is for epub, so basic html/css only (but epub3 so css3 is a possibility even though the e-ink-reader support is spotty)

```css
.body { border-bottom: 1px dotted #334; }
span.gap { border-bottom: 1px solid white; }
```

```html
<p class="body">
text in text <span class="gap">more text</span> and even more text
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try box-shadow:

```css
.body { border-bottom: 1px dotted #334; }
span.gap { box-shadow: 0 7px #fff; }
```

```html
<p class="body">
text in text <span class="gap">more text</span> and even more text
</p>
```

Comment: thanks but that is still making the overlay white which is visible in dark mode

Comment: @SabineR you can use a media query to switch the color

Comment: I tried this https://jsfiddle.net/6n257czg/1/ but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong? I am not well versed in media queries.

Comment: @SabineR add the media query at the end, not the beggining

Comment: Damnit. It worked on the computer but not on tolino (E-Ink-Reader). I'm running out of time today. Will have a look at it tomorrow. Thank you so far.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason as soon as there is a media query, the borders are ignored... No idea why. I hate tolino. It works on thorium etc. but since it destroys the book on tolino it sadly is not an option.